# Python regex assistance

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like this

`24 (prem)-42-48 (6 ext)`

and what I want to get out of it is

`['24 prem', '42', '48', '6 ext']`

I can get the numbers like this:

```
import re
MyString = r'24 (prem)-42-48 (6 ext)'
Splits = re.findall( r'(\d+)', MyString) # ['24','42','48','6']
```

but I lose the succeeding text.

I can also do this:

```
import re
MyString = r'24 (prem)-42-48 (6 ext)'
Splits = re.findall( r'[\\s:\\-]', MyString) # ['24 (prem)','42', '48 (6 ext)']
```

but that misses the `(6 ext)` item.

EDIT after seeing responses:

I think perhaps the simplest way for me to handle this would be to split on numbers and then just use str.replace to get rid of the "(" and " " characters.

So, is there a simple regex statement to split the string before the first character of a number?

The result from performing it on

`'24 (prem)-42-48 (6 ext)'`

would be

`['24 (prem)-','42-',48 (', '6 ext)]`

Comment: So, *what is the pattern*? You gave us one input + expected output line here, but nothing about how the input can *vary*.

Comment: Your last pattern is also invalid; that line of code produces `['-', '-']` and would find all backslashes, colons, dashes the character `'s'`.

Comment: Last but not least, your sample output is a) not Python, and b) not possible with just a regular expression; `['24', 'prem', '42', '48', '6 ext']` is feasible but not `'24 prem'` as the first element.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters thanks for the feedback. You're right, my code is/was really poor. I was using regex hero to try and work it out and didn't double check that python handled it the same way. I've also been doing a bunch of javascript coding recently, so please pardon the '//' instead of '#'. Thanks for fixing that for me.

Comment: So I can go ahead and use zmo's answer of using string replace methods. I had thought there was a regex answer that could use a look ahead to see if there was a word after a number and make a single group out of the number word pair.

Answer (score 2):

to get that result, you do not need regexps, all you need to do is remove the unwanted chars by replacing them with spaces and split the string on spaces:

```
>>> s ="24 (prem)-42-48 (6 ext)"
>>> l = s.replace('(',' ').replace('-',' ').replace('(',' ').replace(')',' ').split()
>>> l
['24', 'prem', '42', '48', '6', 'ext']
```

here's a version using translate for python3:

```
>>> s.translate(s.maketrans("()-", "   ")).split()
['24', 'prem', '42', '48', '6', 'ext']
```

here's a version using regexps:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x is not '', re.findall('[^-() ]*', s)))
['24', 'prem', '42', '48', '6', 'ext']
```

though, I'm considering that the `'24 prem'` and `'6 ext'` in the result list is a typo you made, otherwise there's no generic way to do what you want, though you can achieve this by doing:

```
>>> [" ".join(l[:2])] + l[2:-2] + [" ".join(l[-2:])]
['24 prem', '42', '48', '6 ext']
```

Comment: May be worth adding the regular expression solution as well. Looks like he's just looking for `re.findall([^-() ]*)`. I was considering answering it but I don't think I have anything significant to add

Comment: using str.translate(table[, deletechars]) is a better way a deleting mutliple characters. The example from python docs is >>> 'read this short text'.translate(None, 'aeiou')
'rd ths shrt txt' -- I know the format is screwed up, but you get the point I hope.

Comment: @GaryWalker that's `string.translate` in Python2 and `str.translate` in Python3, but Python3 doesn't allow the optional `deletechars` argument. `str.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "()-"))` in Python3

Comment: except that translate won't work, as he needs not to *delete* chars, but replace them with `" "`.

Comment: For the love of [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid), *when tempted to use `l`, use `L` instead.*

Comment: I'd say bad font, change your font :-). When I lint my python code, there's a lot of rules from pep8 I do disable. Personally, I consider variables with first character uppercased to be a data structure, and full upper case being constants. Here, it's neither of those, thus `l`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to take some guesses about the format of your string, but here is a regex that matches. Notice that you match a "(" character with "(" and use (...) for grouping.

```
 regex = re.compile(r'(\d+) \(([a-zA-Z]+)\)-(\d+)-(\d+) \((\d+) ([a-zA-Z]+)\)')
```

You can find a single match on a line or multiple matches in a bigger block of text:

```
>>> regex=r'(\d+) \(([a-zA-Z]+)\)-(\d+)-(\d+) \((\d+) ([a-zA-Z]+)\)'
>>> re.findall(regex,lines)
[('24', 'prem', '42', '48', '6', 'ext'), ('25', 'prex', '43', '48', '7', 'ext')]
>>> regex= re.compile(r'(\d+) \(([a-zA-Z]+)\)-(\d+)-(\d+) \((\d+) ([a-zA-Z]+)\)')
>>> line='24 (prem)-42-48 (6 ext)'
>>> regex.match(line).groups()
('24', 'prem', '42', '48', '6', 'ext')
>>> lines="""24 (prem)-42-48 (6 ext)
... 25 (prex)-43-48 (7 ext)
... """
>>> regex.findall(lines)
[('24', 'prem', '42', '48', '6', 'ext'), ('25', 'prex', '43', '48', '7', 'ext')]
>>>
```

Comment: This works great based on the input I gave you, but it turns out it won't work for extracting data from other inputs I didn't post. Sorry for providing an incomplete problem statement.

Comment: @nickvans - no problem. this was only intended as a starting point.